# I am having few problems while trying to export report from reporting services(ssrs) to csv

Tags: reporting-services, export-to-csv, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-tablix

I am having few problems while trying to export report from reporting services(ssrs) to csv.

1. I created a textbox which displays total count of the rows below the report body.However, when I export the report from ssrs to csv.I am getting the textbox on top of the report body.But I want to display the textbox below the report body.

My output is something like this:

```
textbox 66

Total rows count:2

id name

1 san

2 jd
```

but when I export to csv I want to show it in this way

```
id name

1 san

2 jd

Total rows count:2
```

2. In the same textbox I don't want to show the text box name('text box 66').I only want to display the count of rows.I tried making changes in data output but it didn't work as it is hiding the text box completely.I only want to display the data in the text box but not the name.

Can you please help me on this.
Many Thanks,
San

Comment: I have never found export to csv works that well. Much better to export to excel and the save as csv.

Comment: It is the client requirement to deliver the report in csv format.So please let me know if you have any work around solution.

Comment: It will only work for the most basic of reports that is one with a fixed number of columns, no hidden cells, no merged cells.  One thing you could try is adding a footer row (Outside group) to your tablix and put the row count in one of the cells .

Comment: Thanks Ewan .But adding the footer row only display rows per every page.But here I only need the total counts of rows for the whole report at the end of the report.That is the reason I didn't use the footer.

Comment: Try making the textbox a part of the main report tablix, as a row under the detail row.

Answer (score 0):

Change the interactive size of the report so that it will fit on a single page (with scrolling). You should then have only a single group footer row.

First though make sure KeepTogether is set to true in the Group Properties. If this does not work try the above.

Hopefully the report is not too large